# Is something wrong with my power supply on my PC?

Tags: power-supply

In August of 2019, I built my first PC with these specs:
Intel Core i7 8700k(CPU)
Nvidia GeForce 1070 Ti (GPU)
16gb ddr4 ram at 3200 mhz by Gskill (ram)
MSI z370 Tomahawk (Motherboard)
NZXT Kraken x62 (cpu cooler)
2tb (hdd)
250gb (ssd)
H500i (case)
EVGA G2 650W (PSU)

So everything with my PC since then has been 100% perfect until a few days ago when I got a new montior. I previously had the LG 25um58-p and I upgraded to the Sceptre e255b-1658a. What I noticed was that when I'm gaming, in highly populated areas my fps dips really low (high 50s, low 60s) but regularly it runs fine at much higher rates. I told my friend about this (who I was in a Discord call with at the time) and he said to check Task Manager and see what part is being overloaded. I noticed that under "Power Usage" the game I was playing was at "Very" High when everything else in Task Manager was at "Low" or "Very Low".

He advised me that my PSU might be bottle-necking my system but wasn't 100% Sure. So I tested other games and the same thing happens. So I ask... Is something wrong with my PC?

Here's a link to the picture of the Task Manager message.
[Task Manager High Usage Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xlyzi.png)

Comment: Can you define “higher rates” as in what was the range prior?

Comment: Also, what about the thermals?

Comment: Your PSU isn't a bottleneck. It is more than enough for the system you describe.  Can you provide a screenshot of whatever you were looking at that displayed Power Usage?

Comment: Valay_17: Before, In the same spot (because it's a lobby) my fps was around 90-100. I haven't checked the thermals yet, but I can today.

Comment: Ramhound: Sure. I will post a picture on my post.

Comment: Valay_17: So this is weird. I checked again for the problem with my FPS and it stayed in between 94-105 which is back to normal. The Thermals were also normal. However, It still says "High Power Usage" in Task Manager.